# Black and white movie where man lands on Earth, is chased, and gets shot in the leg

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been searching for the title of this movie I watched a while back when I was a kid, but I don't remember much about it.

The movie was black and white, and has a spaceship that either lands or crashes on Earth, I think in a city. The door opens and a man comes out; people were expecting an alien but it was a human being. He explains something about leaving Earth years earlier but since he was traveling, at the speed of light I guess, he didn't age at all.

The next thing I remember is that someone was chasing him and shooting at him. He gets shot in the leg and since he's wearing a suit, somehow he clicks something on it and it makes him invisible... That's all I remember.

Comment: If you'd specify how long ago were you a kid, that would for sure help :)

Answer (score 3):

*[The Day the Earth Stood Still](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still)* seems to fit, although this does not look like a leg injury.

A humanoid arrives and scares guards by a sudden move with a device.